# How may I disable all disable-able notifications?

Tags: samsung, android-12

On Samsung Galaxy A13, Android 12.

The nearest I find is:

First, Settings > Notifications > Included apps > All apps (one slider) , but this is missing many notifiers such as Device Care (present on Settings > Apps) and Software Update, System UI, Call (absent from Settings > Apps).

Then, Settings > Notifications > Recently sent > More > All (dozens of individual sliders - for apps oddly missing from Included apps above). This shows entries missing from Settings > Apps e.g. Android Auto. Oddly it shows e.g. Calculator enabled despite that Settings > Apps shows Calculator enabled.

Comment: The "Included apps" are only for selecting which apps are shown as "Brief style". To show all possible apps, from Recently sent > More > All, tap the overflow menu (3 vertical dots) and select "Show system apps".

Comment: "The "Included apps" are only for selecting which apps are shown as "Brief style"." My mistake. Thanks.

Comment: "To show all possible apps, from Recently sent > More > All, tap the overflow menu (3 vertical dots) and select "Show system apps"." Got it. Thanks. BTW, I see no overflow there. The three dots icon looks just like a menu icon to me.

Comment: Ah, I'm too used to [the Android Developer's term for "overflow menu"](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#options-menu)